# Coloured Lines Appearing on App Launch in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I have developed an iOS app in XCode but sometimes randomly when launching this black screen appears with coloured lines at the top and I have NO idea why this is happening.

It happens a lot more when people download from the app store and launch the app.

Is there something in my build settings or code I should be aware of?

Would appreciate any help please as it just looks hideous

[image]

Comment: Looks like memory corruption to me.

Comment: Does this happen before or after the launch image? Is it displayed for a short while and is then replaced with something else? What is the app doing about the time this occurs?